# thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x70 error on appDelegate when clicking save or click back

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate

I get the following error message `thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x70`  when I am in my `addCustomerViewController` and either click save, which at the end of the code runs `self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`, or when I click back in the same `addCustomerViewController`. The line of code highlighted with the error is in my AppDelegate class and its the first line as follows

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{
```

This is the last message I get in the debug area as well. Not sure if it is related.

```
2015-06-17 23:03:03.744 SalesCRM[4930:1409291] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Customer'
```

Here is the save function. Let me know what other code you might need to see. I am lost as to how to fix this.

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


    if firstName.text != "" && lastName.text != "" && phoneNumber.text != ""
    {
        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Customer", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newUser.setValue(firstName.text?.lowercaseString, forKey: "firstName")
        newUser.setValue(lastName.text?.lowercaseString, forKey: "lastName")
        newUser.setValue(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        newUser.setValue(email.text, forKey: "email")
        newUser.setValue(notes.text, forKey: "notes")
        var name = String()
        name = lastName.text!
        print(name)
        var index = advance(name.startIndex, 0)
        print(index)
        first = String(name[index]).lowercaseString
        newUser.setValue(first, forKey: "first")

        let todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"
        let DateInFormat:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate) + ": created"
        newUser.setValue(DateInFormat, forKey: "log")          
        try! context.save()
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Customer")
        let results = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        print(results)

    }
    else
    {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter all information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: did you add @objc("Customer") to your Customer class?

Comment: In your Customer subclass of NSManagedObject did you create a custom initializer for some reason?  In that case it may not be calling the super's initializer and some CoreData funkiness may be causing it to miss it on compile.  Also, in your .xcdatamodeld file when you click on the Customer entity is the "Module" set correctly to your project's name?  That has gotten me several times in CoreData w/ Swift.

Comment: Can you add the Code for your Customer Class? Also if you are using subclasses for your Entities, the new user line (let newUser= ....) should end in as! Customer